# How can you set the x-axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

I have data of shipping dates (1=Jan, 2=Feb ect..) and revenue corresponding to it in a pandas dataframe.

[Data Frame Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niNtu.png)

My code for the line graph that I am trying to make is:

```
finalhelp.plot(x='shippeddate',y='revenue',title='Revenue Per Month')
```

It returns a line graph like this
[linegraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZosG.png)

I tried to fix it by using the code

```
fig = finalhelp.plot(x='shippeddate',y='revenue',title='Revenue Per Month',yticks=([0,20000,40000,60000,80000,100000]), legend=False,)
fig.set_xticklabels(['','Jan','Feb','March','April','May','June','July','August','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
```

I would like to find a way to set each of the x axis to one of the corresponding months, right now it still returns only Jan-June.

It returns this image
[newlinegraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPNUN.png)

Comment: Never set the labels only. Always also set the tick positions. Else, the fixed labels will just appear one by one on the automatically chosen positions. Alternatively plot the dates directly with matplotlib.

Comment: How do you set tick positions? Would it by xticks = [Jan','Feb','March','April','May','June','July','August','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'] in the Fig variable?

Comment: I think in this case if might suffice to set the xticks similar to the yticks `xticks=list(range(1,13))`. (Btw. I think you have an extra empty label in your list, which doesn't belong there.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels`:

```
fig.set_xticks(df['shippeddate'])
fig.set_xticklabels(['Jan','Feb','March','April','May','June','July','August','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
```